# CSS transition and sidebar

Tags: css, transition, sidebar

I am working on making a simple sidebar for my project using css transitions for the sidebar and page-content wrapper.

I noticed that the transition was working for the sidebar but not for the page content that was inside the page-content-wrapper when I used the code below:

```
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    right: 235px;
}
```

But when I used a margin in the code below the transitions were smooth just like I wanted.

```
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    margin-left: -235px;
}
```

I can't seem to understand why would this be the case?

The following is the HTML I am using:

```
<body> 
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
            <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
     <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
          <a class="btn btn-custom" id="menu-toggle">
            <span>MENU</span>
          </a>
          <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand">PROJECT</a>
        </div>
      <div> 
    </nav>

    <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text
              some text some text some text some text some text some text</p>
          </div>     
    </div>    
  </div> 
</div>
<script>
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
</script> 
</body>
```

I am using the following CSS also:

```
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden; 
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; 
    width: 235px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #c8102e;
    right: -235px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    right: 0;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    margin-left: -235px;
}

.btn-custom {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: You haven't provided enough of your CSS (where is the transition property?) Please post the relevant CSS and HTML so that your issue can be recreated.

Comment: Hi mister, I have posted relevant CSS and HTML that I am using in the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are animating on the left and/or right properties, you need to set a value for it to start on by default. So set it to 0, because by default it is set to auto.

So for #page-content-wrapper set it as:

```
#page-content-wrapper { left:0; } 
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper { left: -235px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because when you create a transition effect, you can define the property value that you want it to apply to. eg, width or height, etc. So perhaps in your case it is 'margin' that is defined. To find out, look at the css loaded in your document and find the transition properties that are used.

Comment: Hi I am using the transition properties on the wrapper, sidebar-wrapper and page-content-wrapper..

Comment: So for page-content-wrapper, if you are animating on the left and/or right properties, you need to set a value for it to start on by default. so set it to 0, because by default it is set to auto.

Comment: #page-content-wrapper { left:0; }
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper { left: -235px; }

Comment: Hi party your solution has worked exactly like what I want! Thanks for the help, can you post it as answer so I can accept it.